# Why the code returns negative values in Codility test case?

Tags: algorithm, go

The Codility problem and test case are shown in:[here](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoCM9HYB-MXE/)

The code written in golang:

```
func Solution(A []int, B []int) []int {
    result := make([]int, len(A))
    step := make([]int, len(A)+1)
    step[0] = 1
    step[1] = 1
    for i := 2; i <= len(A); i++ {
        step[i] = step[i-1] + step[i-2]
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(A); i++ {
        result[i] = int(int32(step[A[i]]) % int32(math.Pow(2, float64(B[i]))))
        // result[i] = step[A[i]] & (1<<uint(B[i]) - 1)
    }
    return result
}
```

The `result[i] = step[A[i]] & (1<<uint(B[i]) - 1)` passes all the cases. But `result[i] = int(int32(step[A[i]]) % int32(math.Pow(2, float64(B[i]))))` or `result[i] = step[A[i]] % int(math.Pow(2, float64(B[i])))` results some negative numbers.

It seems something goes overflow. Would anyone know reason? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the exact same arrays for A and B as given in the link that you provided? I don't see any reason why the result would be negative if both A and B consist of small, positive integers.

Comment: The sample array results OK. But after submitting the code, it failed with some cases. Unfortunatly, codilty doesn't show the exactly test case so I've no idea about the array used in the case. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

For some input, you're converting a value in the range `[1<<31, 1<<32)` to an `int32`.

http://play.golang.org/p/6HYPXY9Kjb

```
a := int64(1 << 31)
b := int64(1<<32 - 1)
// int32(a) == -2147483648
// int32(b) == -1
```

Depending on how your algorithm is supposed to work, you need to expand the range to use `int64`, or use a `uint32`, which will truncate the value but remain positive.

Comment: It makes sence! The codility problem assumes `each element of array B is an integer within the range [1..30]`, maybe some test case's inputs exceed that limit.